# Как изменить стиль css, svg элемента при наведении мыши на другой svg элемент?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, style

Как изменить стиль css, svg элемента при наведении мыши на другой svg элемент?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #c1:hover #c2 {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <svg width="500" height="500">
    <circle id="c1" cx="150" cy="150" r="80"
    stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  
    <circle id="c2" cx="350" cy="350" r="80"
    stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить необходимый селектор `+`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #c1:hover + #c2 {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500">
    <circle id="c1" cx="150" cy="150" r="80" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <circle id="c2" cx="350" cy="350" r="80" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Рекомендуется тщательнее продумывать разметку и использовать соответствующие селекторы:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    svg {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #c1 {
      cursor: pointer;
      fill: blue;
    }
    
    #ab {
      transition: 300ms;
      cursor: pointer;
      stroke: #491EC4;
      stroke-width: 3;
    }
    
    #toab {
      transition: 300ms;
      cursor: pointer;
      fill: blue;
    }
    
    #c1:hover~#ab {
      stroke: #008000;
    }
    
    #toab:hover~#ab {
      stroke: #008000;
    }
    
    #ab:hover {
      stroke: #cb0412;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="f1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 700 700" height="100vh">
      <circle  id="c1" cx="300" cy="100" r="20"  />
      <text id="toab" x="50" y="80"> AB </text>
      <line id="ab" x1="50" y1="50" x2="400" y2="50" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо. Имеет ли значение очередность инициализации svg элементов и  стилей элементов в <style> ?

Comment: @СебастианПереира: не совсем понял вопрос. Но, если Вы про то, где размещать `<style>`, то в данном случае значения не имеет. Если же Вы имеете в виду расположение каких-либо элементов в разметке, то да, это критично, и стили будут напрямую зависеть от этого.

Comment: Вот еще вопрос: а почему если я хочу чтобы при на наведении на разные элементы менялся стиль SVG третьего элемента (линии) - этого не происходит?

Comment: И еще не понял как здесь вставить код в комментарий к ответам.

Comment: @СебастианПереира: дополнил ответ. Пожалуйста, [посетите данную страницу](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors) - это азы CSS.

Comment: @UModeL На EnSO есть похожий вопрос, можно и там при желании и времени, ответить  https://stackoverflow.com/q/66223712/7394871